# Jacorb - how to open POA monitor GUI

Tags: java, corba, java-5, jacorb

In Jacorb programming guide there is a mention of "POA monitor GUI". am not sure how and where to open this GUI ? anyone please help me with this ?

"The jacorb.poa.monitoring property determines whether the POA should bring up a monitoring GUI for servers that let you examine the dynamic behavior of your POA, e.g. how long the request queue gets and whether your thread pool is big enough."

Link to the guide : 
http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/corba/JacORB_ProgrammingGuide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get a basic gui by enabling that property and starting your server. It should automatically open the gui.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, am a bit new to jacorb. Could you please let me know the exact process that i need to restart ?

Comment: Change `jacorb.poa.monitoring=on` in your jacorb.properties (and ensure that is picked up by your server). Restart your server and the GUI should automatically show up. You could always try it with the demo/hello example in the JacORB distribution. Note the documentation link you pointed to is not the authoritative location : see http://www.jacorb.org/documentation.html and https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/